# Automatic time synchronization: `ntpdate` works but `chrony` does not

Tags: linux, time, synchronization, ntp, chrony

I have a problem with time synchronization of my Linux server. Both this machine and the NTP server are located in a (smaller) university data center hence the local address.

What is strange is that the `ntpdate` command works:

```
ntpdate -u 172.16.0.25
```

with the output:

```
17 Jan 15:03:53 ntpdate[25993]: adjust time server 172.16.0.25 offset 0.036043 sec
```

However, the `chronyd` does not (it simply hangs):

```
chronyd -q 'server 172.16.0.25 iburst'
```

I was trying all things to set the automatic time sync using `ntpd` but did not succeed and finally resorted to `chrony` but still cannot figure it out.

Here's what happened with `ntpd`. I installed `ntpdate` using the instructions on https://vitux.com/how-to-setup-ntp-server-and-client-on-debian-10. The conf file has a command

```
server 172.16.0.25 prefer iburst
```

while the system status ntp reports

```
Jan 18 10:26:11 akulab1 ntpd[26957]: kernel reports active service TIME_ERROR: 0x41: Clock Unsynchronized
```

The `ntpq -p` has the following output

```
HKS-SRV01.unica .LOCL.           1 u    9   64   15    0.557  2275.65   9.515 –
```

However, after a while the service reports

```
Jan 18 10:31:01 akulab1 ntpd[26957]: ntpd exiting on signal 15 (Terminated)
```

as NTP sync did not succeed. But, the ntpdate -u 172.16.0.25 reports synchronization: 18 Jan 10:33:13 ntpdate[26990]: step time server 172.16.0.25 offset 2.282101 sec (if I am not mistaken...) –
ksonofre
7 mins ago

Here is my `/etc/ntp.conf` file:

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

leapfile /usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

server 172.16.0.25 prefer iburst

restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited

restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

restrict source notrap nomodify noquery
```

I have restarted the NTP service again: `systemctl restart ntp`

The output of the `ntpq -np` is the following:

```
root@akulab1:~# ntpq -np
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 172.16.0.25     .LOCL.           1 u   63   64  377    0.518  104.685  14.815
```

However, the service (`systemctl status ntp`) still reports:

```
Jan 18 11:04:10 akulab1 ntpd[27089]: kernel reports TIME_ERROR: 0x4041: Clock Unsynchronized
```

And, after I set the `timedatectl set-ntp true` the NTP service simply shuts down, i.e. reports inactive.

I have restarted the ntpd service again and it is active. Also, I have waited more than an hour for a sync and it never got it (there is no star or plus in front of the server address) - here is the output of `ntpq -np`:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 172.16.0.25     .LOCL.           1 u   61   64  377    0.588  269.847  14.797
```

Also, this is the output of `ntpdate -qu` command:

```
18 Jan 13:57:44 ntpdate[1975]: no servers can be used, exiting
```

OK, this above command was not complete so with the `ntpdate -qu 172.16.0.25` there is a following output:

```
server 172.16.0.25, stratum 1, offset 0.435131, delay 0.02621
18 Jan 14:51:56 ntpdate[6951]: adjust time server 172.16.0.25 offset 0.435131 sec
```

And the `ntpq -np` gives the following:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 172.16.0.25     .LOCL.           1 u   17   64  377    0.554  436.092  14.279
```

---

The solution is given in an accepted answer below. I assume that the time sync is working now, but I will nevertheless track the clock drift and make an update of my question if it does not synchronize properly.

---

The final solution is posted in this post: [ntp server reachable but never select/set the time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/677523/ntp-server-reachable-but-never-select-set-the-time)

Comment: However, after a while the service reports `Jan 18 10:31:01 akulab1 ntpd[26957]: ntpd exiting on signal 15 (Terminated)` as NTP sync did not succeed. But, the `ntpdate -u 172.16.0.25` reports synchronization: `18 Jan 10:33:13 ntpdate[26990]: step time server 172.16.0.25 offset 2.282101 sec` (if I am not mistaken...)

Comment: Thank you - I have added some new tests and requested outputs. I have also found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423813/ntp-not-updating-with-local-timeserver) but adding `tos maxdist 30` unfortunately does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clock was almost certainly synchronised. The "Clock unsynchronised" is misleading as it only applies while `ntpd` is waiting to synchronise with its upstream sources.

There are two routes for NTP: the `systemd` one (managed through `timedatectl`) and the `ntpd` one (monitored through `ntpq`). I'd suggest you leave `timedatectl` alone.

```
systemctl start ntp    # don't restart ntpd if it was already running
watch -n1 ntpq -pn     # while :; do clear; date; echo; ntpq -pn; sleep 1; done
```

You should see your upstream listed, initially with a reachability of 0, increasing strangely to 377 over a period of about five minutes. It should have a `+` in the left-hand column to show that it's a candidate for time synchronisation, changing to `*` when it's finally been accepted.

The delay and offset fields are measured in milliseconds. Across your university WAN I'd  expect the delay to be low, and 500ns is very good. Offset should tend towards zero over hours and days.

Here's an extract of a steady example from a server of mine. 37ms delay feels reasonable for an xDSL line. The offset from the upstread server is surprisingly low, and the jitter is bearable:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*51.155.16.62    .GPS.            1 u   10   64  377   37.420    0.524  34.067
```

You can view the synchronisation status with NTP's `sysinfo` command. Here, we are looking at the first line of output; notice `sync_ntp`, the presence of which confirms that my client is synchronised with an upstream server:

```
ntpq -c sysinfo | head -n1
associd=0 status=0618 leap_none, sync_ntp, 1 event, no_sys_peer,
```

A final caution. It's *essential* that you don't change the local system's time while you have a service trying to keep the time correct. The service will notice the time change and will assume the local clock cannot keep good time. It will then try really hard to correct the clock, possibly ending up with it slewing so badly the local clock can no longer synchronise with an upstream. See [How often (and when) does NTPD update the time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495145/100397)

If this happens you will either need to wait (a long time) for NTP to notice or fix it yourself. You can fix it yourself by disabling and stopping ntpd (`systemctl stop ntp; systemctl disable ntp`), then deleting `/etc/adjtime` and immediately rebooting. (You may need to do this delete/reboot step twice.) Then use `ntpdate -u 51.155.16.62` to set the time correctly and reboot once more. Finally, re-enable NTP (`systemctl enable ntp; systemctl start ntp`).

If you have `ntpdate` installed you can query the upstream time difference against a nominated server with `ntpdate -qu {server}`. DO NOT try to set the time while `ntpd` is running.

Additional references

- [When will ntp update the time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/337156/100397)
- [How to update date/time without shutting down the NTP daemon?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212477/100397)
- [How to know during system start when system time becomes correct from NTP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206689/100397)
- [System disregards Daylight Saving Time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/275221/100397)

Comment: I will add the info above.

Comment: OK, thanks, the command works fine now. The only 2 questions I have still are: 1. why is the offset constantly rising and not going towards zero (it is now around 420 ms)?, 2. why is there no + or * sign next to the local address in `ntpq -np` command? (sorry for asking so many questions but without the proper time sync I will get the wrong results)

Comment: @ksonofre I've updated the question once more with information on handling a worsening time slew

Comment: OK, I did the steps and restored the ntp service. I have accepted your answer as there is everything explained. I guess this is solved - in any case what I can only do is to monitor the time sync and see whether there would be any drift. Thank you once again for your help!