# Syncing Debian ntpd with Windows time server

Tags: debian, time, synchronization, ntp, ntpd

unfortunately my problem listed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/686714/automatic-time-synchronization-ntpdate-works-but-chrony-does-not) was not solved. It would seem that the issue was not with the `ntpdate` at all: when bypassing the university network all together, time sync works correctly.

The university network where the server resides includes a local time server and the access to external ones are blocked. The access to this time server is set in the configuration file:

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

leapfile /usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

server HKS-SRV01.unicath.LOCAL prefer iburst

restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited

restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

restrict source notrap nomodify noquery
```

However, as shown on the [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/686714/automatic-time-synchronization-ntpdate-works-but-chrony-does-not) and below, time simply does not work:

```
root@akulab1:~# ntpq -np
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 172.16.0.25     .LOCL.           1 u   53   64  377    0.442  45128.2  15.259
root@akulab1:~# ntpdate -qu 172.16.0.25
server 172.16.0.25, stratum 1, offset 45.131138, delay 0.02628
16 Feb 14:29:29 ntpdate[25955]: step time server 172.16.0.25 offset 45.131138 sec
root@akulab1:~#
```

The server `172.16.0.25` (alias `HKS-SRV01.unicath.LOCAL`) is apparently a Windows time server and - as others are blocked - this is the only one I can use.

So, my question is: how to sync Debian NTP service with Windows time server or what do I need to add to the configuration file or to the Debian configuration to make such time sync work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Indeed, this was the problem and adding `tos maxdist 30` to `/etc/ntp.conf` helped so the sync works! Thank you very much once again! Should I write the steps what I did below as an answer?

Comment: If you can still add an Answer here (I suspect you can't) then please do document what you did. Otherwise you can write an Answer on the duplicate, explaining where to add `tos maxdist 30`, because I don't think it's actually described anywhere. I can offer you a +1 in either place if you do.

Comment: Ok, I will answer there - no need to add a +1 - if I can save somebody the amount of time that I spent on this issue is more than enough.